# Positioning dynamically loaded content with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, dynamically-generated

I have a fairly long page of mostly images. It's broken up into separate HTML pages, and when the user gets near the bottom of the page I use JQuery `.load()` to get the next page (infinite scrolling).

However, I'm running into a bit of a problem when loading this content. All my images (for various reasons) are positioned using a Jquery function.

Although I've tried calling this function in the callback on `.load()` and using `.ajaxComplete()` on `$(document)`, this function occasionally seems to fire too soon (i.e. before images are correctly loaded), so it doesn't have effect, leaving lots of the newly loaded images out of place.

The only thing I can think of would be to use a `setTimeout()` or something, but this seems a bit hacky… Is there a better way of doing it? Is the problem perhaps because I'm moving my loaded content from one place to another?

Here's my loading code…

```
$('#load-area').load(content_to_load, function() {
        var loaded_content = $('#load-area').html();
        $('#load-wrapper').append(loaded_content);
        $('#load-area').empty();
        $('#loading2').hide()
});
```

Is there a way to detect when this content is fully loaded and then fire a function?

Answer (score 0):

Try the **.done()** eventhandler

"Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved."

Source here:
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: I don't think .done() works with .load(), from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use .load() again on the content you've asked to be loaded in. Inside that function place the append and any other function you want to run after the content has loaded. See if that works.

```
$('#content-loaded-in').load(function{
   //code to be run after completely loaded 
});
```

Comment: This seems very logical… unfortunately the .load() event doesn't seem to fire correctly.